# Change input spinner number and with that change input value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an item card for a web shop that sels food. What I'm trying to do is that on the first click on the button with the cart icon the amout of item is increased by +1 (now it is increasing by steps that I have set on input element). But I also want it to increase the value (weight/amount) of the product by the step that is defined on the input value and the cart icon has to change to the plus icon (That I managed to do). And for the minus button the logic is reversed... so i click the **-** button the value/weight goes down and amount goes down and if it reaches 0 they should dissaper.

**EXAMPLE:**
I click the cart icon the amount increases to 1 and value/weight increases to 0.25kg... if I click the cart button again the amount goes to 2 and weight increases to 0.5kg. Now if I click the - button the amount goes down to 1 and weight to 0.25kg and if I click it again the amount should go to 0 and weight to 0 and the button wit - icon and the input field should disappear.

MY PROBLEMS:

1. My first problem is that I cant manage to set the amount to increase
   by 1 and value/weight by the defined step
2. My second problem is that my code keeps hiding the [-] button and
   input field on every click not when it reaches 0
3. Is this approach even correct or have I overcomplicated the thing I'm
   trying to do? Is there an easier solution to this?

I'm providing the **jsfiddle in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/weinde/1rhqzofy/32/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=1rhqzofy) link** so that you can have a loot at my code and hopefully understand and help me out with a couple of my problems...

**My HTML layout:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-card-wrapper">
            <div class="product-card">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="product-card-image-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="product-image-link">
                                <div class="product-card-image"></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="prodAmountBox"><span class="prodAmount valueOnChange hidden"></span> kg</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="product-card-body">
                            <div class="product-heading">
                                <h3><a href="#">File mignon</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="heartIT-btn-holder">
                                <a href="#" class="heartIt">
                                    <div class="crossFadeImg">
                                        <img src="./assets/images/heart.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid bottom" />
                                        <img src="./assets/images/heart_black.svg" alt=""
                                            class="img-fluid top transparent" />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc">
                                <p class="m-0">Dry aged steak cca. 250g</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-price-box">
                                <div class="product-price">8,78<span> €/pc.</span></div>
                                <div class="price-per-full-unit">Price per kg: 43.89 €</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-weight">
                                <input id="changedInput" data-name="Item One" data-price="8.78" type="number" value=""
                                    data-decimals="2" min="0.25" max="999" step="0.25" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My javascript + jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner({
    decrementButton: "<strong class='decreaseInCart'>-</strong>",
    incrementButton: "<strong class='addToCart'>+</strong>",
    buttonsClass: 'btn-outline-secondary',
    groupClass: 'flex-nowrap'
  });
  var $changedInput = $('#changedInput');
  var $valueOnInput = $('#valueOnInput');
  var $valueOnChange = $('.valueOnChange');
  $changedInput.on('input', function (event) {
    $valueOnInput.html($changedInput.val());
  });
  $changedInput.on('change', function (event) {
    $valueOnChange.html($changedInput.val());
  });

  //Klik event ki zamenja sliko košarice z plus znakom
  $('.btn-increment').click(function () {
    $('.input-group-prepend').css('display', 'block');
    $('.input-group-text').css('display', 'block');
    $('.form-control').css('display', 'block');
    $('strong').removeClass('addToCart');
  });

  $('.btn-decrement').click(function () {
    $('.input-group-prepend').css('display', 'none');
    $('.input-group-text').css('display', 'none');
    $('.form-control').css('display', 'none');
    $('strong').addClass('addToCart');
  });
});
```

For the input field I'm using [this](https://github.com/shaack/bootstrap-input-spinner) plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are just assigning the value from amount to kilos without processing it. You can solve it with this code `$changedInput.val() * 0.25`.
2. You are hiding the minus button without checking the value. You can solve it by `if($changedInput.val() != 0)`.
3. You can combine selectors if you are performing the same action like this: `$(".input-group-prepend, .input-group-text, .form-control").css('display', "none");`.

You also have an issue with input values:
`<input id="changedInput" data-name="Item One" data-price="8.78" type="number" value="" data-decimals="2" min="0.25" max="999" step="0.25"/>`. Step should be 1 and min should 0.

Here is an example fixing all these issues:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner({
    decrementButton: "<strong class='decreaseInCart'>-</strong>",
    incrementButton: "<strong class='addToCart'>+</strong>",
    buttonsClass: "btn-outline-secondary",
    groupClass: "flex-nowrap",
  });
  var $changedInput = $("#changedInput");
  var $valueOnInput = $("#valueOnInput");
  var $valueOnChange = $(".valueOnChange");
  let $dataFactor = $changedInput.attr("data-factor");
  $changedInput.on("input", function(event) {
    $valueOnInput.html($changedInput.val())
  })
  $changedInput.on("change", function(event) {
    $valueOnChange.html($changedInput.val() * $dataFactor);
  })

  //Klik event ki zamenja sliko košarice z plus znakom
  $(".btn-increment").click(function() {
    $(".input-group-prepend, .input-group-text, .form-control").css('display', "block");
    $("strong").removeClass("addToCart");
  });

  $(".btn-decrement").click(function() {
    if ($changedInput.val() != 0)
      return;

    $(".input-group-prepend, .input-group-text, .form-control").css('display', "none");
    $("strong").addClass("addToCart");
  });
});
```

```css
/*___Color_variables___*/

.product-card-wrapper {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.product-card {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-card .product-card-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.product-card .product-card-image-wrapper a .product-card-image {
  height: 220px;
  background: url("https://sharpmagazineme.com/uploads/2018/10/05102018195139.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.product-card .product-card-image-wrapper .prodAmountBox {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 9px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  font-size: 0.875em;
}

.product-card .product-card-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-heading {
  width: 95%;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-heading h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-heading h3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .heartIT-btn-holder .heartIt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.product-card .product-card-body .heartIT-btn-holder .heartIt .crossFadeImg {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .heartIT-btn-holder .heartIt .crossFadeImg img {
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .heartIT-btn-holder .heartIt .crossFadeImg .transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-desc {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-desc p {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 9px;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-prepend .input-group-text,
.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-append .input-group-text {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000000 !important;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-prepend button,
.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-append button {
  color: #000000 !important;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-prepend {
  display: none;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .input-group-append .btn-increment .addToCart {
  content: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/1022/32/png-transparent-shopping-cart-icon-shopping-cart-logo-icon-shopping-cart-label-coffee-shop-shopping-mall.png");
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-weight .input-group .form-control {
  display: none;
  padding-right: 6px;
  flex: unset;
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  color: #000000 !important;
  background: transparent;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-price-box {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-price-box .product-price {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-price-box .product-price span {
  font-size: 0.675em;
}

.product-card .product-card-body .product-price-box .price-per-full-unit {
  margin-top: -5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #797979;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/_bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-card-wrapper">
      <div class="product-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="product-card-image-wrapper">
              <a href="#" class="product-image-link">
                <div class="product-card-image"></div>
              </a>
              <div class="prodAmountBox"><span class="prodAmount valueOnChange hidden"></span> kg</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="product-card-body">
              <div class="product-heading">
                <h3><a href="#">File mignon</a></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="heartIT-btn-holder">
                <a href="#" class="heartIt">
                  <div class="crossFadeImg">
                    <img src="./assets/images/heart.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid bottom" />
                    <img src="./assets/images/heart_black.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid top transparent" />
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <p class="m-0">Dry aged steak cca. 250g</p>
              </div>
              <div class="product-price-box">
                <div class="product-price">8,78<span> €/pc.</span></div>
                <div class="price-per-full-unit">Price per kg: 43.89 €</div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-weight">
                <input id="changedInput" data-name="Item One" data-price="8.78" type="number" value="" data-decimals="2" min="0" max="999" step="1" data-factor="0.50"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for this example :) thanks. 
One more question tho... what if the weight modifier is different on another item... lets say item 2 has weight 0.5kg... how can i set the multiplier in the js then?

Comment: You can a data attribute containing the multiplying factor then use that in JS. I updated my answer to reflect this. I added `data-factor="0.50"` to `#changedInput`. You can change it to any number your like.

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem can be solve by wrapping these statements.

```
$(".btn-decrement").click(function(){
    if (someValue === 0){
      $(".input-group-prepend").css('display', "none");
      $(".input-group-text").css('display', "none");
      $(".form-control").css('display', "none");
      $("strong").addClass("addToCart");
    }
});
```